# Parameters for camera_pose_calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-calibration, camera-pose-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the camera_pose_calibration package, which seems easy to use. Thank you! Can you help me understand some of the parameters:

PatternParameters pattern_width: Is this the # of dots in a row?

PatternParameters pattern_height: # of dots in a column?

PatternParameters pattern_distance: distance between circle centers? in meters?

neighbor_distance: The readme says this is distance between pixels. In meters, I guess? I think this should be a small number with a RealSense camera, like 0.1mm

Finally, is this [OpenCV "asymmetric circle grid"](https://nerian.com/support/resources/patterns/) the type of pattern to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258014/parameters-for-camera_pose_calibration/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
Are you referring to the old version, or the new package?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-03-28**:
This one: [camera_pose_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_pose_calibration)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
Yeah, so the Indigo version?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-03-28**:
Ah, yes. Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameters that worked for me with a RealSense R200 and the circles pattern from https://nerian.com/support/resources/patterns/ (printed on US letter size) were:

```
srv.request.tag_frame = "calibration_circles_frame"; // This is defined in a URDF. It's known.
srv.request.camera_frame = "camera_ee_depth_frame"; // Unknown pose. Find its relation to target_frame
srv.request.target_frame = "base_link"; // This is defined in a URDF. It's fixed

  camera_pose_calibration::PatternParameters circle_pattern;
  circle_pattern.pattern_width = 4; // 4 circles wide
  circle_pattern.pattern_height = 11; // 11 circles long
  circle_pattern.pattern_distance = 0.038; // Distance between circle centers. [m]
  circle_pattern.neighbor_distance = 1; // Expected distance between pixels of image
  circle_pattern.valid_pattern_ratio_threshold = 0.5; // Min. ratio of valid pixels to NaN's
  srv.request.pattern = circle_pattern;
```

I still had an unexplained 45 degree rotation and a Z-offset, but those were easy enough to correct manually. So it was easier than calibrating by hand, for sure.

The RealSense is more tricky than most cameras, I think, because the point cloud is published in the frame camera_depth_optical_frame, which is a child of camera_depth_frame. So camera_depth_frame is what actually needs to be attached to camera_link in the URDF. Maybe this was the cause of the extra rotation -- which I corrected for with an extra transformation matrix.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's all in accordance with OpenCV:

- The text in the link you provided states that it is compatible with the asymmetric circles grid, so that should be fine. Otherwise, you can download it here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/_downloads/acircles_pattern.png
- I would assume that the unit of the neighbor distance is up to you, whatever you choose, just be consistent with the units everywhere. It's correct that this is the distance between two adjacent circles.
- The pattern_width and pattern_height for the asymmetric circles grid is explained here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html.

---

Originally posted by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) with karma: 103 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-03-28**:
^This helped a little bit with pattern_width and pattern_height. So, thanks! But I'm still having issues. Maybe I'll ask a new question.